# Fail to install NVIDIA GTX1080 driver

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

My ubuntu is 14.04 LTS. And I tried to install NVIDIA driver.
I typed

1. `sudo service lightdm stop`
   and entered tty.
   And then
2. `sudo init 3`to make sure it was text only.
   Next I typed
3. `cd Desktop` (because the .run file was already on my desktop) and
4. `sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-384.90.run`
   the result was
5. `command not found` 
   I was confused.Because I just successfully installed another .run file(Matlab) earlier.
   If anyone could explain this I would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Don't install the drives from the `.run`. Install from Additional Drivers

Comment: I installed this for the first time and there is no additional driver. I am using  the default Intel® HD Graphics 630

Comment: Open the Additional Drivers, select the recommended Nvidia driver and apply. Because you're still with 14.04 (any special reason not to use a newer release, 14.04 has been superseded by the current LTS, 16.04) you may need to add the Graphics Drivers PPA  in order to access newer and more adequate driver version for the GTX1080. New hardware begs for new software.

Comment: I found that I just need to add a  `sh` after `sudo`. It perfectly worked. But thank you!